# ESP8266-01 Resetting when DC motor runs

Tags: esp8266, motor, reset

```
DC motor: 3-6v 
Servo sg90: 3-7.2v
Esp 8266 01: 3.3v
```

I have 2 Arduino Uno both has their own ac-dc power adapter. 
Lets say, 1st Arduino is `Ard1` and 2nd is `Ard2`.

The `Ard1` communicates to a web server (BLYNK) with Esp 01.

Using I2C, `Ard1` sends command to `Ard2` to power/move the DC motor/Servo.

So far, **it has no problem operating with Servo**. But,

Whenever the `Ard1` commands the `Ard2` to power the DC motor.

Right when the DC motor runs(using `digitalWrite(motor,HIGH)`) the Esp 01 resets.

---

- Tried using `analogWrite(motor, 102)` though it won't reset instantly, prolong usage randomly resets it anytime.
- I also tried to test operating Servo and DC motor simultaneously in `Ard2` using Serial commands, without I2C/Esp01. There was no problem at all, both works flawlessly.

Below is the diagram of the wiring.
[image]

Comment: That‘s an electronic issue. You should post a circuit diagram or move this question to electronics SE

Comment: You should check the current rating for motor. It may be the case that your supply is not able to provide it.

Comment: How is the ESP-01 powered/?

Comment: I've just included a diagram for further understanding. Please pardon me, I have zero knowledge on electronics/electrical.

Comment: Despite the fact that you don‘t have pull-ups connected to the I2C lines your circuit looks fine. How do you know that the esp resets, what did you observe?

Comment: Using blynk app, as simple as on/off for any of the motor. Once I 'on' the DC motor and it runs, the connection between the esp and server will be cut. Which also means I can't 'off' the DC motor from the Blynk app unless the connection between the server and esp resumes/restarted. I suppose the problem would be the wiring of I2C/GND(ard1 - ard2), as It's the only way these two is linked.

Comment: The connection between the Arduinos probably has nothing to do with the esp resetting. From the information you provided I‘m not convinced that the esp really performs a reset, maybe the esp simply doesn’t send anything. Have you added the pull-ups?

Comment: Try removing the second arduino and uploading a program to the one connected to the motor that turns the motor on and off, to see if you still have the problem. Try powering the motor from a separate 5 v supply so it is only connected to the arduino by pin 3

Answer (score 1):

Can you clear one thing that you are giving power to dc motor from 5v pin given on Arduino board or from your ac to dc power supply. If you are giving power to the motor from 5v pin of Arduino Uno then there is a high possibility that the motor is not getting sufficient current because 5v supply on Arduino comes from onboard lm1117 5v voltage regulator and cheap clon Arduino has a cheap regulator with less than 1amp capacity.

Comment: It was indeed. I then resorted to a 9v battery supply for dc however problem still exist but not that severe, it still cuts the connection. Finally, my latest solution was attaching a 10ko resistor between esp's ch_d to 3.3v of arduino and 1k between gnd and esp's rx and another 1k between esp's rx to arduino's. So far everything went well.

Comment: @Kolokoy what are These resistors supposed to do?! Note that a 9V battery is also a bad choose as I can‘t provide much current as well. You better use a proper PSU or e.g a Li-Ion battery

Comment: Someone I knew said rx/tx might uses a TTL logic level of 5v instead of 3.3v which the esp 01 can only take. I also found a tutorial on YouTube on the wiring of esp01 to arduino and followed it. The battery was just to test if problem would still exist when the dc motor has different power supply, I will not use it in the final outcome.